# dplyr sample by groups of values

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make samples based on grouped values with dplyr  :

What I tried :

```
 id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)

 id <-  as.data.frame(id)

 sample <- id %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   sample_n(2, replace = FALSE) %>%
   ungroup(id)

sample
```

Expected result ( n sample =2) :

```
1, 1, 1, 2
```

or

```
1, 1, 1, 3, 3
```

or

```
5, 5, 5, 6, 6
```

etc.

I have got an error:

```
Error: `size` must be less or equal than 1 (size of data), set `replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement
```

Comment: If you are grouping by 'id', there are elements with less than 2 rows

Comment: I want to make sample based on id. "Sample" mean  rows corresponding at 2 types of id : ex: 5 and 6 (5, 5, 5, 6, 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
id %>% 
  distinct(id) %>% 
  sample_n(2, replace = FALSE) %>% 
  inner_join(id, .)
```

Comment: The distinct /  inner_join is very smart